# Can you package a WPF application as a DLL with a small .EXE loader

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

What I want to do is make a WPF application, and then package it all into a DLL, and have a lightweight updater on the main exe, so you can update the app without having to have a separate updater process. Can I do this?

Comment: You don't need that. Use ClickOnce or similar deployment technology.

Comment: @HighCore That's a better idea, if I had a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run a WPF application off a DLL.